# QTableView column control to facilitate show/hide columns

Tags: python, qt, qtableview

The Java [JXTable](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTable.html) has a column control to let users show/hide columns.

Does QTableView have anything similar? I know there's [an API call to show/hide a column](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableView.setColumnHidden), but that doesn't help when you are using a program with a QTableView.

Answer (score 1):

Use the horizontal header from table and call hide section passing the index that you want to hide, i link this to a signal from a context menu that gets the index of column that was right clicked

`table_view->horizontalHeader()->hideSection(index);`

Edit: and similary to show columns

`table_view->horizontalHeader()->showSection(index);`

get the index from a QPoint (which i get from the point of where a context menu is requested from)

`int index = table_view->horizontalHeader()->logicalIndexAt(cursor_pos);`

Comment: this doesn't make sense to me. Are you putting up a popup window?

Comment: i add a custom context menu to the QTableView (which gives you a point from which you can get the current index of the table, added example in code) so from this you can hide that row. to bring them back i use a pop up window showing a list of removed columns(by just storing the indexs of which ones are removed with a column name so you can display something) then call the show function on the columns you have selected to show again but calling the show section function i show above

Comment: I won't be able to try it until next week, unfortunately.

Comment: ok well im sure this works anyway like i said iv done this myself with a highly customizable QTableView class so let me know if it doesnt

Comment: urk, I don't remember unfortunately.